# Why I cannot delete JDOM nodes with a loop properly in a thread?

Tags: java, jdom

I would know why my code below raises a problem that some of nodes in xml file are not deleted actually as supposed to be deleted.

I need to maintain an java application, the purpose of this application is to compare two PDF files. the application pulls data from two servers in xml files; then it  deletes some nodes in both of xml files to ignore certain sections, finally the application sends the two manipulated xml files back to the two servers to get PDF files, and pulls PDF files to compare in bytes. The application uses JDOM API to parse and manipulate xml files.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Ignores all Changes of this Form
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
protected void ignoreChangesSection() {
    Element formNumberElement=retrieveElement(getSiapXmlDocument(), FORM_REQUESTED_ELEMENT).getChild(FORM_NUMBER_ELEMENT);
    String formNumber=formNumberElement.getText();



    /*retrieveElement(getSiapXmlDocument(), DATA_ELEMENT).getChild(APPROACH_RESOURCE_INSTANCE_ELEMENT).
                                          getChild(APPROACH_ELEMENT).removeChildren(CHANGES_ELEMENT);*/

    Element approachElement = 
        retrieveElement(getSiapXmlDocument(), DATA_ELEMENT).getChild(APPROACH_RESOURCE_INSTANCE_ELEMENT).
                                      getChild(APPROACH_ELEMENT);

    List changeReasonList1 = approachElement.getChildren(CHANGES_ELEMENT);

    if (changeReasonList1!=null)
    {           
        for (int i=0; i<changeReasonList1.size(); i++)
        {
            Element chngRsn = (Element)changeReasonList1.get(i);

            String ind = chngRsn.getChildText(REASON_CHANGE_IND);

            if (ind != null && !"".equals(ind))
            {

                if (ind.equals(CHANGE) || (formNumber.equals("8260-7A") && ind.equals(CHANGE_FORM_7A)))
                {

                    chngRsn.detach();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

There are 9 nodes with exactly same name as "ChangeReasons" under approachElement, whether I should delete them depends on the value of attributes of "REASON_CHANGE_IND", so I use a loop to do this work.  However, there is often one of nodes that is supposed to be deleted is not actually deleted. And this problem happens from time to time, not every every time. I suspect it is related to thread. As there are 2 threads which are doing the same job, deleting the same nodes from a different xml file. However, the object is created inside each thread, whose class has this method. so I suppose no thread would know anything about other thread. if I use removeChilren as I commented in the code, I do not have this problem. but it removes all of nodes, not certain nodes that I want to remove. Could anyone give me a hint why this problem happens and any solution?

Thanks a lot!

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you detach the node, you also reduce the size of the list by one.... consider a list of four nodes, A, B, B, C.

You want to delete/detach B nodes

In your loop, you iterate and start with 0, and then move to 1.... you delete node 1. But, now your list is: A, B, C and your index is 1. Then you loop again, and your index is 2, which points to C, and you then exit the loop.

You do not delete the second node B.

This is a general computing bug, you cannot easily delete nodes from a list while looping through the list.

Java provides an Iterator, which JDOM implements too, and that would be your right choice... now, you should be using JDOM 2.x and not JDOM 1.x. 2 would be easier, but, even with JDOM 1.... use an iterator:

```
for (Iterator it = changeReasonList1.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Element chngRsn = (Element)it.next();
    if (various reasons) {
        // detach the element:
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

***Edit, update from comments:***

The two key points are that:

1. `emt.detach()` removes `emt` from it's parent.
2. `approachElement.getChildren(...)` returns a 'live' list. Changes to the list are reflected in the element, and visa-versa.

So, when you loop through the luve list and get the `emt` as an indexed `get(...)`, you are getting a child element. When you detach that child, you are disconnecting it from the parent, and thus also removing the child from `approachElement` list. The list shrinks by one.

So, your loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<changeReasonList1.size(); i++)
```

when you do:

```
chngRsn.detach();
```

in essence you are also doing:

```
changeReasonList1.remove(i);
```

That is the key point..... you are effectively doing remove(i) in a list loop. If you take JDOM out of the quation, and have a simpler situation:

```
List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(1);
data.add(2);
data.add(3);

for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("before: " + data.get(i));
    if (i == 1) {
        data.remove(i);
    }
    System.out.println("after: " + data.get(i));
}
```

With the above code, it will work, and print:

```
before: 1
after: 1
before: 2
after: 3
```

and exit.....

As a result, it will never 'test' the before value `3` because, bu removing `2`, we shrink the list, and for the last loop, the size is 2, and the index is incremented in the loop to 2, and thus the loop is terminated.

The Iterator avoids this.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help! It works!I would understand why I detach a wrong node in my previous code. I did not use any index as parameter for detaching; I get the ith element and decide whether I should delete it or not, if I should delete this node, I use detach. When I was tracking in debugging mode, I notice if I detach a node, the list does shrinks, and I think I am detaching the right node, otherwise the control flow cannot reach detach. so why does this problem happen? I would really appreciate if you would give me more hint.

Comment: Edited to include more detail